# About x87 FPU precision

Tags: assembly, fpu, x87

In the Intel IA-32 software developer manual. It says that bit 8 & 9 of x87 FPU control word determines the precision of floating-point calculations. The default precision is double extended precision. After the instruction "FINIT" is executed, the precision is set to double-floating.
  The problem is that, after "FINIT" is executed, x87 FPU use only 64 bit of the 80-bit data registers to calculate. And the FPU can't accept(output) double-extended precision floating value from(to) memory. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not right. The FPU automatically converts from 64-bit to 80-bit when loading from / storing to memory.

Comment: Thanks. Then what's the purpose of the precision control?  It's used to control what?

Comment: To control the intermediate precision. This is useful if you want reproducible behaviour.

Comment: The precision control selects how many digits the FPU internally computes.  Lowering precision speeds up FPU computations (or at least used to) and allows you to exactly emulate a 64 bit or 32 bit FPU with the x87 FPU without having to constantly store and reload its registers to get rid of the extra precision bits.